# not converting more the 10 sec of audio (wav) file

Tags: python

getting results but it only converts the 10 sec of audio to text not more than that i tried with different audio files

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.AudioFile("E:/g.wav") as source:
    audio = r.record(source)
try:
    s = r.recognize_google(audio).count(60)
    print("Text: "+s)
except Exception as e:
    print("Exception: "+str(e))
```

please help

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a mistake in the code you provided. I imagine what you wanted was

```
import speech_recognition as sr
    r = sr.Recognizer()

    with sr.AudioFile("E:/g.wav") as source:
        audio = r.record(source)
    try:
        s = r.recognize_google(audio)
        print("Text: " + s)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Exception: "+ str(e))
```

I tried running this with [this sample file](https://www.signalogic.com/melp/EngSamples/Orig/male.wav) and it recognized the entire thing, not just the first 10 seconds, so I cannot reproduce your problem.

Can you try with the same file I did?

Comment: I have run that code again that you suggested to me with audio file male but the error still remains

Comment: Then it is probably something related to your environment. Is everything updated to the latest version?

Comment: I run that code again with that wav file that you suggested and it works this time thanks for that but it doesn't work with other wav files any guess(BTW those wav files were converted from MP4 format)

Comment: Have you tried listening to the .wav files to make sure nothing was lost on the conversion from mp4?

Comment: yes i listen the whole audio its perfectly fine and i also download some wav file they didn't work as well